# Java Swing Object[][] getData() confusion

Tags: java, arrays

Hi I'm having some trouble getting started with a problem in a Java course learning Swing and starting on JTables and getting data into them. It's going to be hard to explain so I'm just going to post the code I was given, along with the question.

**The question is:**
The getData() method needs to return an Object[][] containing the data represented by the class.

**The first class is MusicAlbum**

```
class MusicAlbum {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String genre;
    private boolean isCompilation;
    private int track_count;

    public MusicAlbum(String id, String name, String genre, boolean isCompilation, int track_count) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.isCompilation = isCompilation;
        this.track_count = track_count;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public boolean isCompilation() {
        return isCompilation;
    }

    public int getTrackCount() {
        return track_count;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof MusicAlbum)
            return this.id.equalsIgnoreCase(((MusicAlbum)obj).id);

        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}
```

**The class I have to implement the methods in is MusicDataObject (at the bottom)**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MusicDataObject {
    private List<MusicAlbum> albums = new ArrayList<>();
    private Random random = new Random(); // for generating IDs

    public void addAlbum(MusicAlbum album) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (searchAlbum(album.getId()) != null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Album ID is not new!");

        albums.add(album);
    }

    public MusicAlbum searchAlbum(String id) {
        for (MusicAlbum album : albums) {
            if (album.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
                return album;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public MusicAlbum removeAlbum(String id) {
        MusicAlbum album = searchAlbum(id);
        albums.remove(album);

        return album;
    }

    public void updateAlbum(MusicAlbum album)
      throws IllegalArgumentException {

        if (removeAlbum(album.getId()) == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Album ID does not exist!");

        addAlbum(album);
    }

    public String generateID() {
        String formatter = "A%0" + (int)Math.ceil(Math.log10(albums.size() * 2) + 1) + "d";
        String ID;

        do {
            ID = String.format(formatter, random.nextInt(albums.size() * 2 + 1));
        } while (searchAlbum(ID) != null);

        return ID;
    }

    public void saveData(String fileName) throws IOException {
        // make sure that the file exists or try to create it
        File fout = new File(fileName);
        if (!fout.exists() && !fout.createNewFile())
            return;

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fout);

        for (MusicAlbum album: albums) {
            out.println(serializeAlbum(album));
        }

        out.close();
    }

    public String serializeAlbum(MusicAlbum album) {
        return String.format(
          "%s;%s;%s;%b;%d",
          album.getId(),
          album.getName(),
          album.getGenre(),
          album.isCompilation(),
          album.getTrackCount());
    }

    public void loadFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        albums = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            // --- split the next line with the character ";"
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(";");

            // --- construct a new MusicAlbum using the resulting tokens. NOTE: This isn't very robust.
            //      If a line doesn't contain enough data or the data is invalid, this will crash
            albums.add(new MusicAlbum(
              tokens[0],
              tokens[1],
              tokens[2],
              Boolean.parseBoolean(tokens[3]),
              Integer.parseInt(tokens[4])
            ));
        }
    }

    // ----- these methods need to be implemented

    public Object[][] getData() {
        // TODO
    }

    public String[] getColumnNames() {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

The sample data being used is in a txt file, formatted as so:

A01;Defiance;Soundtrack;true;24

A02;Insomniac;Punk Rock;false;14

A03;A Great Day For The Race;Gypsy Jazz;false;10

A04;Viva La Internet;Ska;false;31

A05;New Surrender;Rock;false;17

So basically it's this getData() method they want me to implement that is giving me grief. I don't fully understand what they want me to do, nor do I fully understand what the Object[][] does.

I hope I have been clear enough, and I will appreciate all help given. Also please try to explain things as best you can and dumb them down as much as possible, I'm new to a lot of this :)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Object[][] is a two dimensional array of objects. So you should return such object array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object[][]` is a 2-dimensional array. Each of its element is an `Object[]`, a one-dimensional array.

Your task is to create a 2 dimensional array, having one element (`Object[]`) for each of your `MusicAlbum`. An `Object[]` should hold the properties of a `MusicAlbum` like `id`, `name`, `genre`, `isCompilation` and `track_count`.

You can create an object array like this:

```
Object[] arr = new Object[] { "some", "values", 23, true };
```

You can create a 2 dimensional array like this:

```
Object[][] arr2d = new Object[size][];
```

And you can iterate over all your `MusicAlbum`s, create an `Object[]` for each of them containing the properties of that music album, and set it in the `arr2d`.

You can set/get elements of a 2-dimensional array just like any other arrays:

```
// Set first element:
arr2d[0] = arr;

// Get first element:
Object[] firstElement = arr2d[0];
```

The `getColumnNames()` method should just return a `String[]` (a String array) containing the column names, the names of the properties.

And it might be obvious but note that the order you return the column names and the order of the property values (in the elements of the `Object[]`) should be the same.